# jstree for json value is giving some error

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

My Json:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"ungrouped","icon":"/icons/Group_16x16.png",  
  "parent":0,"dashboard":null,"childrenList":null}]
```

MY jS:

```
// ajax demo

    $('#ajax_topo').jstree({
        'core' : {
          'data' : {
            'url' : './topology.json',
            'data' : function (node) {
              return { 'id' : node.id };
            }
          }
        }
    });
```

My Html :

```
<h1>AJAX Topology demo</h1>
<div id="ajax_topo" class="demo"></div>
```

I am getting this

> Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Json array. So you have to apply indexing on it.

Replace `node.id` to `node[0].id`

```
$('#ajax_topo').jstree({
        'core' : {
          'data' : {
            'url' : './topology.json',
            'data' : function (node) {
              return { 'id' : node[0].id };
            }
          }
        }
    });
```